# aws_lambda_invocation > Conditional

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am passing some values to a lambda function, and then invoking it.  It works great.

I have several of these depending on each other, and some resources in the depends chain too.

```
Invoke_1 > Invoke_2 > aws_glue_catalog_database > Invoke_3
```

However, the lambdas are listed out as 'read' in every plan, end executed on every apply.

Firstly, this makes the plan harder to read. The lengthy output (listing all the values I have passed) means it is harder to spot real changes to other resources.

Secondly, it's running a function that does not need to be run and that's just not *clean*.

**So ..**

Is there a way to make these invocations conditional in a way that does not mess up my dependency chain?

```
// zips the python file in order to be used by lambda
data "archive_file" "lf_settings_1_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/scripts/lf_settings_s1/"
  output_path = "${path.module}/scripts/s1deploy.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lakeformation_settings_1" {
  function_name    = "dlsettings_1"
  filename         = data.archive_file.lf_settings_1_zip.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lf_settings_1_zip.output_base64sha256
  role             = aws_iam_role.myRole.arn
  handler          = "main.main"
  runtime          = "python3.8"
}

locals {
  lf1_json = <<JSON
  {
            "account":"${local.account_id}",
            "principals":[
              "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/Role1",
              "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/Role2"
            ]
        }
  JSON
}

data "aws_lambda_invocation" "invo1" {
  function_name = "dlsettings_1"
  input         = local.lf1_json
  
  depends_on = [
    aws_lambda_invocation.invo0,
    aws_lambda_function.lakeformation_settings_1
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Would you please start by formatting your code:
`terraform fmt --recursive` on your terraform directory

Answer (score 2):

Data sources still allow for the `count` parameter. I'm not exactly sure how you would implement it with your current terraform code, but this is the idea. If the `var.boolean_youcreate` is set to false then it doesn't invoke it:

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "example" {
  count         = var.boolean_youcreate ? "1" : "0"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function_test.function_name

  input = <<JSON
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
JSON
}

output "result_entry" {
  value = jsondecode(data.aws_lambda_invocation.example.result)["key1"]
}
```

Comment: Not quite. The Lambda function itself is hashed, and that infra does not get updated unless it is needed to. However, the invoke is a 'data' block, which does get listed on every plan, and triggered on every apply. It is the invoke data block that I wish to make conditional on the 'input' values I pass it.

Comment: with regard to  terraform fmt . My code is run via Azure DevOps, So not sure I can call that command localy. I will have a chat to our admin and see what my options are, it looks like a helpful tool I'd like to take advantage of - thanks.

Comment: updated my answer. In regards to the `terraform fmt` command, as long as you have the terraform binary in your path, you should be able to run it. Word of caution, make sure that you dont interact with the terraform state because it might mess some things if versions of terraform differ.

Comment: ooh, crafty ! I like this. Will get on to trying this out a little later today and get back to let you know results. Thanks for now ....